# Why is my output showing twice the limit I have entered?

Tags: c

> Write a C program to print all even numbers between 1 to 100. - using while loop

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a=0,Even,Go;

    printf("Enter the Value:\n");
    scanf("%d",&Go);
    
    while(a<=Go)
    {
        Even=a*2;
        printf("%d\t",Even);
        a++;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

OutPut:

```
Enter the Value:
20
0       2       4       6       8       10      12      14      16      18      20      22      24      26       28      30      32      34      36      38      40      %
```

Comment: You're printing twice the value of `a`. If `a` goes to 20, the printed value goes to 40.

Comment: Why is there a `scanf()` in there anyway? The assignment doesn't ask you to prompt for a number at all. Also, if you're supposed to start from 1, shouldn't you do just that?

Comment: You do not need the `Even` variable. Just print `a` and increase `a` by 2.

Comment: I don't understand why you are confused by this result. Try tracing through the logic of the program. What values of `a` allow the loop to keep running? What will the corresponding values of `Even` be? If you write `while(a<=Go)`, why would you expect the loop to stop when `Even` reaches `Go`? Does `Even` appear in that line of code? No? Then how can it care about that value?

Comment: I feel like this issue falls under 'simple debug'

Comment: Because the computer is doing what you told it to do.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, your `while` condition is not based on the numbers that you're printing. You're testing the number and then doubling it when printing.

Instead, you can simply increment by 2 so you test the same numbers you're printing.

Since the numbers should be between 1 and `Go`, you should initialize `a` to `2` rather than `0`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int a=2,Even,Go;

    printf("Enter the Value:\n");
    scanf("%d",&Go);
    
    while(a<=Go)
    {
        printf("%d\t",a);
        a += 2;
    }

    return 0;
}
```